# Using spatial index in SQL Server gets "Failed to open malformed assembly 'mscorlib'"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, spatial, spatial-index

I'm having a bit of an issue with setting up a db in MSSQL where when I try to set up an index on a geography data typed column and it keeps spiting out an error of

**Msg 6507, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Failed to open malformed assembly 'mscorlib' with HRESULT 0x80070008.**

here is the code

```
        /* do this last as everything is keyed to it */
        IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[place]') AND type in (N'U'))
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[place]
        GO
        IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysfulltextcatalogs ftc WHERE ftc.name = N'ft_placebyname')
        DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG [ft_placebyname]
        GO


        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[place](
            [place_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [prime_name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
            [abbrev_name] [nchar](10) NULL,
            [street_address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
            [creation_date] [datetime] NULL,
            [updated_date] [datetime] NULL,
            [coordinate] [geography] NULL,
            [plus_four_code] [tinyint] NULL
                CONSTRAINT [CK_plus_four_code_check] 
                CHECK ([plus_four_code] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' AND [plus_four_code] NOT LIKE '0000'),

            CONSTRAINT [PK_place] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
                [place_id] ASC
            )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
            ) ON [PRIMARY]
        GO
        /* create the indexing by long and lats */
        CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SIndx_place_geography_coordinate
           ON [place]([coordinate])
           USING GEOGRAPHY_GRID
           WITH (
            GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_4 = MEDIUM), 
            CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 64,
            PAD_INDEX  = ON,
            SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
            DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
            ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
            ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        GO  

        /* create the indexing by primary name */
        CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_place_prime_name ON [place]([place_id]);
        CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft_placebyname AS DEFAULT;
        CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [place]([prime_name])
            KEY INDEX ui_place_prime_name 
            WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;
        GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW,
SQL Server 2008 R2: Command(s) completed successfully.

A really quick google for this:

> Not enough storage is available to process this command.
>
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008) (mscorlib)

Any chance you're out of drive space?

And another post:

> SqlServer process ran out of memory (HRESULT 0x80070008). I will file
>   a DCR to make the error message better.

Seems like either a memory or drive space exhaustion issue?

Comment: well.. hmm.. there is 59gb hd but it does seem that the server with only 3.75gb @ 95% usage may indeed be bottomed out.  Is there anyway to test the queries to watch the memory usage and tell if it's really that cause the error is near instant when I run it and seems odd it don't hang the pc under that condition.  tk -J

Comment: Unsure about the memory usage question. Try restarting the MSSQLSERVER process (or maybe just bouncing the box entirely) and re-executing the query. Other thoughts: have you tried splitting this script into pieces, and running one-at-a-time, and if so, what particular statement fails to execute as part of this batch?

Comment: what you see is what is run.  Really it's nothing and if the server can't run thing I'd be in the camp that the server has some other issue.  I can only trust that the query is right.  We did restart the server, as it turns out it's just under that load at 3.75gb @ 95% usage.  I can't say much else at the moment, but I would like to know how much memory is needed to use the spatial indexes and why it's so beefing in needs.  tk for the help.. Cheers -J

Comment: What did you end up finding out?

Comment: oh sorry I hought that it was clear and rereading it's not :D .. it was an out of memory issue.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks for the follow through.